# 5.1.1 Basic Funtion Call Output

Tags: python, function, output

I have been trying to get this to output correctly. It is saying I'm not adding a line break at the end.

I was wondering, how I could add the line break? From my understanding the code is for the most part right.

I also need to have it take in another output that Zybooks generates itself, so I can't just simply put two print statements of ('*****')

```
def print_pattern(): 
    print('*****') 

for i in range(2): 
    print(print_pattern())
```

Expected output:

```
***** 
*****
```

My output:

```
***** 
None 
***** 
None
```

Comment: You are printing the result of `print_pattern()`. It returns `None`. That's why you're getting an unexpected output of `None`.

Comment: can you paste the code instead of a screenshot ?

Comment: *"It is saying I'm not adding a line break at the end."* -- It's not saying that, it's actually saying that your output has two `None`s that shouldn't be there. So I've closed your question as a duplicate of existing questions that cover the same issue/topic. But if there's something I've misunderstood, LMK.

Comment: The code it has immediately is
def print_pattern():
    print('*****')

my solution is the 
for i in range(2):
    print(print_pattern())

which gives me the out put of
******
******
with no white space in between. However, it wants me to add the white space. Is the print statement not defining the print_pattern?

Comment: Also, please read [ask], which covers how to write a good title. And [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: wjandrea thanks still learning on how to use this community. Brand new to all of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to work, you have to return a value like this.

```
def print_pattern():
    return '*****'

for i in range(2):
    print(print_pattern())
```

You function isn't working properly because you are trying to print something that has no return value. If you return something and try to print like I have done in my code here, it will work.

Edit.

Since you cannot change the print_pattern() function, the correct way to do this would be like this.

```
def print_pattern():
    print('*****')

for i in range(2):
    print_pattern()
```

You just do a for loop where you run the function at the end of each loop. The print function my default adds a new line at the end of the print.

Comment: The problem now is that the name `print_pattern` doesn't match what the function does. I'd actually take this the other direction: print in `print_pattern`, and don't print its return value.

Comment: I cannot change the def print_pattern(): or the print('*****').

Comment: could you paste the code in your question with the expected output, its hard to see what the output needs to be exactly from a screen shot @wjandrea

Comment: oh that's easy then, take a look at my answer in a minute

Comment: @anarchy Oh, I'm not OP.

Comment: my bad, @oCosmic take. look at my answer now

Comment: def print_pattern():
    print('*****')

for i in range(2):
    print(print_pattern())

expected output:
*****
*****
my output:
*****
none
*****
none

Comment: there's white space in between all that. I'm on my phone.-.

Comment: hey @oCosmic I edited you question, could you take a look at it and see if its correct

Comment: @oCosmic also please take a look at my answer at the bottom, I think it's the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @anarchy thank you so much. From what I understand I was print the function rather than the variable because of the print statement?

Comment: @oCosmic because you already have a print function within the function you are running, you don't have to run the print function the function itself. in a way yes, you are printing the function rather than printing a variable. you should just run the function. if my answer helped please tick it correct. thanks!